# How do I force warbler to use a specific version of jruby?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

My packaged war created by warbler keeps using `jruby-core-9.2.0.0` to run. How can I force warbler to package the war file with the jruby version I want?

Answer (score 2):

in your *Gemfile* specify:

`gem 'jruby-jars', '9.2.0.0', platform: :jruby, require: false`

`bundle install` and re-`warble`